# Responsive Background img + make text position where i want with responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm pretty much stuck on a site that I'm trying to build in the responsiveness part
And in the position of the text.

The `img` background - [image]

What I try to do it to make the `img` background full cover in big screens
and on the small screen, I want that they will see the ball in the `img` - it only works for me for big screens.

Next to this, I want to put `H1` and `p`, but I want it will be near the ball in the background `img`

My code:

```js
/* hamburger */

const hamburger = document.querySelector("#hamburger");
const navUL = document.querySelector("#nav-ul");

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    navUL.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
html,body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.container{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn{
    background-color: #222f3e;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover{
    color: #2e86de;
    background-color: #fff;
}
/* Header */
header {
    background-image: url(./img/main-img.jpg) ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom center ;
    background-size: cover;


}
/* Navbar */
#navbar{
    padding: 10px;
}
#navbar .container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.hamburger{
    display: none;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hamburger:focus{
    outline: none;
}
#navbar ul{
    padding-right: 0;
}
#navbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.logo a{
    padding: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Showcase Section */
#showcase{
    min-height: 700px;
}

#showcase .container{
}



@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    #nav-ul{
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #nav-ul.show{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .hamburger{
        display: block;
    }


   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;1,400;1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./mystyle.css">
    <title>Football</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <div dir="ltr" class="container">
                <h1 class="logo">
                    <a href="./index.html">Natan Football</a>
                </h1>

                <button class="hamburger" id="hamburger">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <ul id="nav-ul">
                    <li><a class="btn"href="#">צור קשר</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn"href="#">מה מציעים</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn"href="#">קצת עלינו</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn" href="./index.html">דף הבית</a> </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <section id="showcase">
            <div class="container grid">
                <h1>some text asgfasfgfdfgdg</h1>
                <p>dsgsdgdfgdfgdg</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        
    </header>
    
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please provide image background

Comment: hey , I added in the post.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/08nIZ.jpg
I dont know to add it to the code project so i upload alone

Answer (score 0):

here i have provided a very basic code cause i don't have your full code. 
I just added few css properties for you needs. If you run this code on big screen the `.text` will be top and center of the page. and you go in small screen text will be near the ball as you asked. You can even use `px` for `height`. It's just an example to show you.

```css
body {
        background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/08nIZ.jpg");
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
      }
      .text {
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        body {
          height: 40vh;
        }
        .text {
          top: 50%;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="text">
        <h1>some text asgfasfgfdfgdg</h1>
        <p>dsgsdgdfgdfgdg</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Let me know if it doesn't work for you.